# Parse a space delimited line with proper names

Tags: python, file, csv, text

I have a text file delimited by spaces.

The format is:

LastName FirstName value1 value2

LastName can be Van Horn or Roberts or Silly Last Name - hard to know how many spaces.

FirstName can be the same - multiple words with spaces.

Value1 is one of 4 fixed values but also contains spaces

Value2 is the same format as Value1

I think because Value1 has a fixed 4 known values I should be able to at least get “LastName FirstName”, Value1, Value2

I want to convert a file of this data to cab file. Preferably LastName, FirstName, Value1, Value2

I am struggling with the logic though.

Thanks for any help anyone can provide to get me going.

**Code I have tried (parts of it from this site):**

```
input_file = open("file.txt", "r")
for line in input_file:
    (LastName, FirstName, Value1, Value2) = line.strip().split(" ")
    print(LastName, ",", FirstName, ",", Value1, ",", Value2, "\n")
input_file.close()
```

**File.txt:**

```
Van Horn Sir Steven Value1 v1 Value2 V2
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Van Horn, Sir Steven, Value1 v1, Value2 V2
```

**Will Accept:**

```
Van Horn Sir Steve, Value V1, Value V2
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tokyomike\Desktop\parse.py", line 4, in <module>
    (LastName, FirstName, Value1, Value2) = line.strip().split(" ")
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)
```

Comment: Provide your code. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Updated post with the information requested. Thank you.

Comment: The error message shows, that your first line of your Python File does not consist of interpretable code. Just put the comment character in the beginning of the first line: `#Van Horn ...`.

Comment: thanks - too many edits - corrected that - error now reflects running code. I know I am asking the code to split by " " and that I need some sort of logic to split everything before Value1 and after Value1 since this value is a fixed set of 4 unique values. I just need some help from here - how to do this splitting, and then how to recognize multiple word first and last names.

Comment: I would say the data source has a very bad format, because a computer can never know what is a "last name" and what is a "first name", unless you tell it. Just from parsing the string you cannot determine the last name from the first name.

Comment: Is the text file also under your control? If so you should make the fields comma separated instead of space separated.

Comment: Text file is not under my control. I would accept the following logic:

psuedo-code

for each line:
   for each word:
     if word is (one of the 4 unique values of Value1):
        string = (text before value1),(value1),value2

realize this is hard if Value1 has spaces too, but I am hoping I can search for Value1 = "Value V1" or "Value V2" ie. with spaces

Comment: You could remove any `value2` from the end of line, then remove any `value1` from the end of line, but then you'd still have to figure out how many words belong to the first name and how many to the last name. Test cases: `William Henry Gates III`, `George Herman Walker Bush` (hint: Walker could be interpreted as a last name too, it was his mother's maiden name), `Vezetéknév Tamas` (hint: Vezetéknév is the person's family name) etc etc etc.  See also https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split()` function deletes all the white spaces and accepts each as an individual element. Therefore in your case `Van Horn Sir Steven Value1 v1 Value2 V2` you will have 8 individual values but you are unpacking them under just **4 variables** `LastName, FirstName, Value1, Value2`. This is what raises the `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)` error.
Lets test:

```
x,a,s = [1,2,3,4]
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 1, in <module>
    x,a,s = [1,2,3,4]
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Exactly the same error.

**The Solution:**

```
import re

string = 'Van Horn Sir Steven Value1 v1 Value2 V2'
str = re.findall(r'(\w+?\s\w+)', string)
str = ', '.join(str)
print(str)
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
Van Horn, Sir Steven, Value1 v1, Value2 V2
```

In your case:

```
import re

input_file = open("file.txt", "r")
for line in input_file:
    str = re.findall(r'(\w+?\s\w+)', line)
    str = ', '.join(str)
    print(str)
input_file.close()
```

Comment: What if the whole name consists of an uneven number of words?

Comment: This gives me a strategy. Once I figure it out I will post it. I will use the Regex to find one of the 4 fixed values of Value1. Then I will have isolated the Lastname FirstName mess - the values will be to the left of Value 1 and Value2 is to the right of Value1. I will mark this as the solution as it gives me an idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So - first of all - regarding your exception: the `split()` splits the given string on every .
This of course leads to a list longer than the four items you are trying to unpack it into:

```
line = "Van Horn Sir Steven Value1 v1 Value2 V2"
print(line.split())  # ->['Van', 'Horn', 'Sir', 'Steven', 'Value1', 'v1', 'Value2', 'V2']
```

You could use asterisk unpacking to solve that:

```
line = "Van Horn Sir Steven Value1 v1 Value2 V2"

*name, key1, val1, key2, val2 = line.split()
print(f"name: {name}, {key1}: {val1}, {key2}: {val2}")

# Output-> name: ['Van', 'Horn', 'Sir', 'Steven'], Value1: v1, Value2: V2
```

This will leave you with a list of elements within `name`.

At this point you might notice:
Your approach in general has one major flaw.
We cannot know, where a surname begins / the family name ends, because they can have any number of elements.
So it's basically impossible to solve.

Unless: Your example includes a "Sir".
If every name does have a "Sir", "Madam", "Mr." or any fixed keywords basically, one could generate a list of those keywords and split the list at the first occurence of one of those words into first and last name.

Comment: It's not really feasible to compile an exhaustive and unambiguous list of all honorifics in the world, or even in the English language.

Comment: Certainly not. But it might not be necessary depending on the use case.
Wherever OPs data is coming from, there might be only two or three of them, which are actually used...